# Reloading a combobox with DisplayMember and valuemember

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a Combobox that I populate on the form loading binding it to a data table i am using a Displaymember and a valuemember. My problem is when the user clicks to add a new user it writes to the Data base and i want to reload the Combox (cbouser). I have tried to clear the combobox (clearitems) prior to reloading, i set the datasource = null. but i keep getting an error  Additional information: Cannot bind to the new value member. what is happening. it loads correctly on the form load but not when i try to reload the combo box

```
prvate void loaduser()
{
            cboReportedBy.DataSource = null;

            cboReportedBy.Items.Clear();

            DataBase userData = new DataBase();
            DataTable udt = userData.getusers();
            cboReportedBy.DataSource = udt;
            cboReportedBy.DisplayMember = "username";
            cboReportedBy.ValueMember = "userID";
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but it was my query 
`select 0 as userI,'' as username union all Select userID, username from dbo.users order by username`

i fat fingered the select 0 as userI it should have been UserID. i fixed that all is good. strange that is loaded on the formload but not on the second call.